# Botões em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma página com botão de salvar, mas toda vez que ele é clicado aparece o script de que as informações foram salvas e sai da página.
Meu objetivo é que ele não saia, mas olhei o código e não entendi porque ta saindo. 
Segue o botão:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 botao">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" name="button" id="button">Salvar</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 botao" >
            <button type="button" name="button" id="button" class="btn btn-danger form-control">Cancelar</button>
        </div>
```

Segue o Script:

```
<script>
    var retorna = function () {
        window.location = "a_pagina_anterior.php";
    }

    var button = document.querySelector("#button"); 
    button.onclick = retorna;
</script>
```

Comment: Está faltando algum trecho de código ? Até onde me lembro history não é uma função, o history você pode chamar o back() e forward()

Comment: Não. Eu uso o sublime text e ele acusa quando algo é reconhecido ou não como uma função. Estava tentando usar window.history.back()

Comment: Abra um console em algum browser e digite window.history()

Comment: Realmente, não é uma função. Mas não entendo porque meu window.history.back() não funciona.

Comment: Agora sim kkk, seu back não funciona ?

Comment: Refaça sua pergunta novamente assim vou poder te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Certo. Quando meu botão salvar é clicado, a página retorna pra anterior. O código em jscript é esse aí, olhei várias vezes e parece tudo certo, tentei inclusive desabilitar o script mas continua acontecendo o mesmo.

Comment: Mariana, o código que você está utilizando é realmente o que está na pergunta? reveja o código

Comment: Opa. correção, window.history.back() não, window.history.forward()

Comment: O código que você postou da erro porque usa o history como function.

Comment: Ah, tem razão, o código está errado. Esse é o código que eu já mexi até dizer chega, vou editar para o original.

Comment: Tudo bem, assim que mudar comunique, tente colocar o código inteiro ok?

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo sua pergunta, ele sai da página porque você está utilizando o

```
window.location
```

Explicação:

O objeto window.location pode ser usado para obter o endereço da página atual (URL) e para redirecionar o navegador para uma nova página.

Comment: Sim, eu tentei colocar o endereço da própria página que eu quero manter, mas continua voltando na página anterior

Comment: Como expliquei o window.location vai alterar sim a página independente se você passa a mesma página ou uma diferente.

Comment: Você pode estudar um pouco sobre ajax e utilizar para fazer seu cadastro, assim você permanece na página.

Comment: Certo, obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: De nada, qualquer coisa pesquise sobre crud com ajax e php, vi que você utiliza php, se minha resposta respondeu sua pergunta não esqueça de avalia-la, até a próxima.

Comment: Eu ainda não tenho 15 pontos de reputação.

Comment: Não faz mal, só comentei porque sempre faço isso kkk, obrigado e precisando estaremos aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar o  window.open e configura-lo de acordo com a sua necessidade:

```
<script>
 var windowObjectReference;
 var strWindowFeatures ="menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";

 var retorna = function () {
    windowObjectReference = window.open("a_pagina_anterior.php", "_blank ", strWindowFeatures);
}

var button = document.querySelector("#button"); 
button.onclick = retorna;
```

O segundo parametro do window.open é o modo em que ele irá que são:

```
_blank - O link abrirá em uma nova janela
_self - O link abrirá no mesmo frame onde foi clicado
_parent - O link abrirá no frameset pai
_top - O link abrirá na mesma janela, sem frames
```

A variavel strWindowFeatures é referente as configurações da nova janela: para mais detalhes: [Window.open](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: Então, o problema é que abre uma nova página semelhante a original quando eu uso o trecho que você respondeu. o que deveria acontecer é simplesmente salvar as alterações sem sair da página.

Comment: @MarianaFerreira usa o _self, e outra, o seu php ja funciona?

Comment: Funciona. Vou tentar.

Comment: Usei o _self e nada aconteceu. Desculpa a pergunta, sou meio leiga na linguagem, mas isso é Orientação a Objeto?

Comment: Tranquila @MarianaFerreira, é orientado a objetos sim.

Comment: @MarianaFerreira Edita a pergunta e posta o seu código, talvez fique mais facil.